# HTML 5 disable attribute wont submit value to database

Tags: php, html

I have a form and if the user is logged in, fields like name and mobile number will be retrieved from their account database and also i would like to disable the inputs fields as well.

Here is the code for reference:

```
 <?  if ($usernamefromdatabase==$username) { ?> <input type="text" size="150" name="name" value="<? echo $givenname?>" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{1,20}" disabled> <? }
else { ?> <input type="text" size="150" name="name" value="" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{1,20}" autofocus required/> <? }  ?>
```

The code works and i did saw the field disabled and auto filled up. However when i have submitted, i cross checked with my database; the disabled fields did not save at all.

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Disabled inputs are ignored when sending info through php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **point** of `disabled` is to stop the field being submitted. Perhaps you are confusing it with `readonly`?

> When set, the disabled attribute has the following effects on an
>   element:
>
> - Disabled controls do not receive focus.
> - Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
> - **Disabled controls cannot be successful**.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled

Comment: ahhh.. let me try readonly then. Disabled have a more cool effect though.  EDIT: ok i tried. It works. Thanks btw!